# In Java, is a type of "a.ByteArray" equal to "[B"?

Tags: java

I am comparing two pieces of code and trying to figure out why one works and the other does not.

In both programs, there is a variable declared with:

```java
byte[] operatorAndTokenHolder = ...
```

In the first I run

```java
System.err.println(
  operatorAndTokenHolder.getClass().getName()
);
```

and this gives

```
"a.ByteArray"
```

when I run that line on the other code it returns:

```
"[B"
```

Are these types equivalent? And how could I further inspect the type of this supposed `byte[]`?

Comment: `[B` is the class name for an array of byte. `System.out.println(((Object) new byte[0]).getClass().getName());`

Comment: There is nothing *here* that will print `a.ByteArray`. Merely citing 'that other program' without posting it is not sufficient.

Comment: Maybe there's some bytecode manipulation that's replacing references of `byte[]` with `ByteArray` found in some package `a`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Or maybe `package a; class ByteArray {...}`. Maybe anything. It isn't up to us to guess. It is up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: @user207421 It's something for him to look towards. This is what the comment section is for. May not be the answer, but it's a possibility.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It's something for him to provide source code for here so it can be analysed. Comments are really not for enumerating the infinity of possibilities. Otherwise SO would be intolerable.

Comment: @user207421 That's opinion based & biased - let's stay on topic. OP, if dumping byte code from class files doesn't show any signs of manipulation, look for agents that may be manipulating the code at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `byte[]` class has a class name `"[B"`.  See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) for `Class::getName`.

> And how could I further inspect the type of this supposed `byte[]`?

Well it definitely is `byte[]` ... if that's what `getName` is showing you.

How else could you demonstrate that?   How about:

```
 oneThing.getClass() == otherThing.getClass()
```

Or something with `instanceof`.

I think you have missed something else<sup>1</sup>.  Look at how / why you are getting `"a.ByteArray"` as the supposed name of something that is supposedly declared as `byte[]`.  If it is an array class the first character of the class name should be `'['`.

<sup>1- Some possibilities: bytecode manipulation on one the classes, looking at the wrong source code file, problems with build or deployment procedures.  Probably others too.</sup>